# union of infinitely many prime ideals

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Consider a noetherian ring $R$ and a collection $m_i$, $i\in I$ of maximal ideals of $R$. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$.  It is well-known that if the collection is finite (i.e. the index set $I$ is finite), then $P\subseteq \cup_{i\in I}m_i$ if and only if $P$ is contained in one of the $m_i$. (This is true under weaker assumptions.)

Now my question is what about the case of an infinite collection. Does the same hold (under suitable assumptions, e.g. $R$ is normal integral, etc.)? Or can anyone give a counter-example?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I fixed your notation so that there wasn't any equivocation. I changed $P_i$ to $m_i$, changed the ideal $I$ to $P$, and kept the set $I$ as $I$.

There is indeed a counterexample. Take $R=\mathbb C[x,y]$, the prime ideal $P=(x,y)$ is not contained in any of the ideals $m_{a,b}=(x-a,y-b)$ for $(a,b)$ not both $0$, since $P$ is also a maximal ideal. Yet every element of $P$ is contained in at least one of the $m_i$, because there is no polynomial function on $\mathbb A^2$ that vanishes on one point but not any other point. Thus $P \subset \bigcup_i m_i$.

Comment: [edited only to fix the typo "prime ideal ideal"]

Comment: That seems like an ideal ideal reason to edit.

Comment: What if I add a condition that these prime ideal $P_i$ are subset of $P$.

Answer (score 12):

On a related note, however, there are some important classes of rings $R$ where *countable prime avoidance* holds.  That is, when an ideal $J$ is a subset of a *countable* union of prime ideals in such a ring, it has to be contained in a single element of the collection.  In particular, $R$ satisfies countable prime avoidance if either:

1. $R$ contains an uncountable field, or
2. $R$ is a complete Noetherian local ring.

Case 1 was mentioned in an article by Hochster and Huneke in the Michigan Math. Journal in 2000. Case 2 was proved by Lindsay Burch in 1972.  Both arguments are fairly straightforward.

I learned these things from the Hochster-Huneke article some years back.

Comment: It seems "enumerate" does not work well, so I removed it. Yet merely numering the lines (or just starting them with 1.) has a similar effect, which I thus did.  

Answer (score 7):

As another counterexample, take any noetherian local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ of dimension $>1$, such that $\mathfrak{m}\not\in\mathrm{Ass}(R)$. Then $\mathfrak{m}$ is subset of the union of all *non maximal* prime ideals, because any $x\in\mathfrak{m}$ lies in a prime ideal of height $\leq1$.

Comment: Nice example ! But why do you assume $\mathfrak{m}$ is not an associated prime ?

Comment: That is a good point. I was being "too" cautious when I wrote the answer, but the assumption $\mathfrak{m}\not\in\mathrm{Ass}(R)$ is not needed.

Answer (score 7):

As an addition to the answers already given, let me mention the interesting paper *Baire's category theorem and prime avoidance in complete local rings* by Sharp and Vamos (Arch. Math. 44 (1985), 243-248). Beside other things, it contains the following:

- A neat proof of Burch's Lemma (cf. the answer by Neil Epstein) on use of Baire's category theorem.
- An example showing that in Burch's Lemma the hypothesis of completeness cannot be omitted; this is essentially the same as the example given by Mahdi Majidi-Zolbanin.
- A noetherian local ring with uncountable residue field has countable avoidance (i.e., if an ideal is contained in the union of a countable family of ideals (not necessarily prime!) then it is contained in one of these ideals); this can be viewed as a generalisation of a special case of the Hochster-Huneke result mentioned by Neil.

Comment: Actually, the countable avoidance result (without assuming any of the ideals are prime), at least when the ring contains an uncountable field, also appears in the Hochster-Huneke paper. Perhaps they weren't aware of the Sharp-V\'amos result, or maybe it was just that their result had slightly different hypotheses. Avoidance (prime, countable, or otherwise) wasn't the main point of their paper anyway; it was about tight closure theory and the localization problem. In any case, thank you for the interesting reference!

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question asking myself, when a prime ideal $P$ is a minimal prime ideal of a principal ideal. This is clearly equivalent to $P$ being strictly larger than the union of all prime ideals $Q \subsetneqq P$, which leads to the question after generalizations of prime avoidance.

I also found this article by Chen (Infinite prime avoidance, 2017) giving some results that might be interesting for you:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.05496