# Localization and intersection

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, counterexamples

It is very well known that if $\mathfrak p_1, \ldots,\mathfrak p_n$ are prime ideal of an integral domain $A$, then we have the equality$$S^{-1}A=\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_{\mathfrak{p}_i},$$ where  $S:=A\setminus\cup_i\mathfrak p_i$.

For a proof of the above, see for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337826/intersection-of-two-localizations).

Now I'm asking myself if the equality above holds true for any family (infinite) of prime ideals. Any reference or counterexample would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not true. Morally, the right hand side corresponds to the functions that are regular at all $\mathfrak p_i$, and one can show that this is not always a localisation of the entire ring $A$.

**Example.** Let $(E,O)$ be an elliptic curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, and let $P \in E(k)$ be a non-torsion point. Let $X = E \setminus \{O\}$, and $U = X \setminus\{P\}$. Then $X$ and $U$ are affine, and $U$ is not a principal affine open of $X$ (see e.g. [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/7185/82179)).

If $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$, then $P$ corresponds to a prime $\mathfrak p \subseteq A$. We consider the intersection
$$\bigcap_{\mathfrak q \neq \mathfrak p} A_\mathfrak q \subseteq \operatorname{Frac} A$$
and the set
$$S = A \setminus \bigcup_{\mathfrak q \neq \mathfrak p} \mathfrak q.$$
(In either case, it doesn't matter whether we include the zero ideal as well or only the maximal ideals.)
We claim that $S = A^\times$. Indeed, clearly $A^\times \subseteq S$. Conversely, suppose $f \in A$ is not in $A^\times$. Then $V(f)$ contains a point $Q \neq P$, hence $f$ is contained in a prime $\mathfrak q \neq \mathfrak p$. Thus, $f \not \in S$.

This proves that $S = A^\times$, and therefore $S^{-1}A$ is just $A$. But if $B = \Gamma(U,\mathcal O_U)$, then
$$\bigcap_{\mathfrak q \neq \mathfrak p} A_{\mathfrak q} = \bigcap_{\mathfrak r \in \operatorname{Spec} B} B_{\mathfrak r} = \Gamma(U,\mathcal O_U),$$
which cannot be equal to $A$ because $X \not \cong U$. $\square$

Answer (score 6):

With a view to understand to which extent OP's identity can fail, I am sharing these easy **positive results**. The emphasis is on the fact that OP's question tightly relates to (generalizations of) the [prime avoidance lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_avoidance_lemma) for ideals of denominators.

Let $A$ be an integral domain. Let $(\mathfrak{p}_i)_{i \in I }$ be an arbitrary family of prime ideals of $A$. Let $S = A \setminus \bigcup_{i \in I} \mathfrak{p}_i$.

> **Claim 1.** The inclusion $S^{-1}A \subset \bigcap_{i \in I} A_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$ always holds. If moreover $\{\mathfrak{p}_i\}_{i \in I}$ contains the set of all maximal ideals of $A$, then $A = S^{-1}A = \bigcap_{i \in I} A_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$.
>
> *Proof.* Elementary, see e.g., [1, Theorem 4.7].

Let $R$ be an arbitrary commutative ring with identity. We say that $R$ satisfies the *[prime avoidance lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_avoidance_lemma) for unions of cardinality $\kappa$* if for every ideal $I$ of $R$ and every index set $K$ of cardinality $\kappa$, the inclusion $I \subset \bigcup_{k \in K} P_k$ implies $I \subset P_l$ for some $l \in K$, where the ideals $P_k$ are arbitrary prime ideals of $R$.

Note that the prime avoidance lemma for countable unions holds for some interesting classes of rings, see for instance the answer of Neil Epstein to this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102546/union-of-infinitely-many-prime-ideals). For more on prime avoidance, I recommend [Exercises 3.16 to 3.20, 2]. The bleeding-edge results on infinite prime avoidance are as of today in [3].

> **Claim 2.** If $A$ is [GCD domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain), or satisfies [the prime avoidance lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_avoidance_lemma) for unions of cardinality $\vert I \vert$, then $S^{-1}A = \bigcap_{i \in I} A_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$.
>
> *Proof.* Let $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I} A_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$ and let $\mathfrak{d} = \{ d \in A \, \vert \, dx \in A \}$ be the *ideal of denominators of $x$*. Then we have $\mathfrak{d} \not\subset \mathfrak{p}_i$ for every $i \in I$. If $A$ is a GCD domain, then $\mathfrak{d}$ is a principal ideal generated by some $d_x \in S$, thus $x \in S^{-1}A$. If $A$ satisfies the prime avoidance lemma for unions of cardinality $\vert I \vert$, then we certainly have $\mathfrak{d} \cap S \neq \emptyset$, so that $x$ has a denominator in $S$.

---

[1] H. Matsumura, "Commutative Ring Theory", 1986.
[2] D. Eisenbud, "Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry", 1995.
[3] J. Chen, ["Infinite prime avoidance"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05496), 2017.